# Ubuntu failed to load - black screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot

Using dualboot Ubuntu/Windows desktop.

A black screen which appear after loading up the "Ubuntu" symbol. Then the screen prompted "No Input, entering sleeping mode". I wait for several minutes and no response. I reboot and got the same result.

Pressing the down arrow key show a flashing cursor on black screen.

[image: The screen go black after this splash screen.]

The screen goes black after this splash screen.

=========================================================

What I did today to the system:

- Install a `zsnes` via `apt-get`
- Tried to install `fceux` with [this tutorial](http://maxolasersquad.blogspot.hk/2013/08/compiling-fceux-on-ubuntu.html), but it didn't work
- Boot up Windows and played with it for a while.

What I tried after Ubuntu failed to load:

- Went to recovery mode, select the "DPKG package recovery" option, yes all the way. It did removed some packages. After reboot, the problem returned.
- Tried to boot up windows and no problem. So most likely this is not hardware problem.

Any easy way to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! I'm having difficulty understanding much more than black screen at boot. Please try to add clarity to your question. Did you try searching for an answer prior to posting this question? Look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is the `lightdm` interface.

I followed this article and installed `gdm` then booted into Ubuntu successfully : http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/ubuntu-lightdm-black-screen-when-using.html

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

Then I switched the default interface to `gdm` instead of `lightdm` when it asked. After that the problem was avoided.

Then I tried to reinstall `lightdm`:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm
sudo dpkg-configure lightdm
```

Then I reboot the PC and it works fine and I can log in successfully with `lightdm`

Answer (score 0):

The `splash` kernel option might cause LCD monitors to enter sleep mode during the boot process when using DVI input.

In the `grub` menu, select the entry for Ubuntu and press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit it, then remove the `splash` option from the kernel line and boot.

If this solves your problem, you can make the change permanent by editing `/etc/defaults/grub` and removing the `splash` option from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.

Answer (score 0):

On boot, press <kbd>E</kbd> (this puts you in edit mode) use arrow keys to move cursor to the line that says quiet splash. Backspace the "quiet splash" type in no mode set (then press <kbd>F10</kbd> key) the screen will be blank when you hear the drive go quiet press <kbd>Space bar</kbd>.